# I cannot get a GUI on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gui

I have gone through multiple guides on how to set up a GUI for my Ubuntu server 14.04.
However all have failed.

I tried using other Linux operating systems but they too have failed at attaining a GUI.
The following Linux OS's have been tried: CentOS 7, Fedora, and Ubuntu Server 14.04

All of this was done on a OVH hosted VPS server, I cannot just install an OS that comes with a GUI as they do not provide such OS's.

After following almost all guides I keep getting to a point where the final thing needed was for me to run this command:

```
startx
```

However upon entering that command I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you install ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a VPS server; you can't use a GUI normally because you don't have a monitor attached directly to it; that's why `startx` won't work.

A VPS is meant for use as a server, not as a desktop.

Maybe you could [use a VNC server](http://secure.quickweb.co.nz/system/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=1) but I've never tried it.

Comment: Umm well he does have a screen - he gave us pictures. Please try to add links in line. [Here is a page about how to.](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#links)

Comment: I mean a screen connected to the server; that picture is from his local computer or workstation using SSH to connect to a remote computer (VPS).

Comment: While I've never done it personally, wasn't X designed specifically to allow server/client connections across the internet? Again, it hasn't worked for me, but `ssh` has a `-X` option for doing exactly that.